# Gulp script messes up git repository (?)

Tags: javascript, git, laravel, gulp, browser-sync

Is there any probability a simple gulp script (running under laravel installation) messed up my git repository?
Without any visible reason (no add, no commit, only file editing) at one point all files in git repository folder is marked to add.
"git status" return me **all** files and folders are deleted, and to *re* add it all.
this is the gulp script:

```
gulp.task('foorwatch', function() {
    gulp.watch([config.SASS_SRC])
        .on("change", function(file) {
            gulp.src(file.path, { sourcemaps: true })
                .pipe(plumber())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
                .pipe(changed(config.SASS_SRC, {hasChanged: changed.compareLastModifiedTime}))
                .pipe(sass())
                .pipe(minifycss())
                .pipe(sourcemaps.write('maps'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(config.CSS_DEST))
        });
});

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.task('foorwatch')
        .browserSync({proxy: config.PROXY});
});
```

If not, what can cause a behaviour like this?
I'm using OSX with VSC and zsh as terminal shell.
The repository is on a ssh mounted folder and all git commands are executed via ssh connected terminal.

Thanks

Comment: Are the files still there?

Comment: Yes, all the files still present.
Seem it all was "unstaged" or removed from git...

Comment: I think it would be easier to help out if you could provide us with a repo where one could reproduce this.

Comment: It would be easier, i know but sorry this is not possible, these are sensitive sources..